# How to create a JSON object in Qt using ScriptEngine class?

Tags: json, qt, scriptengine

How to create a JSON object in Qt using ScriptEngine class?
So far anybody has tried,Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: I think http://qjson.sourceforge.net/ is good enough for Qt4. You don't have to use ScriptEngine.

Comment: If you don't interact with other JavaScript code, you can use QJson instead of ScriptEngine. ScriptEngine is designed mainly for interacting with JavaScript.

Comment: Here iam interacting with JavaScript.The object passed to JavaScript has to be JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

JSON in JavaScript is almost equal to a normal Object.

In Qt, evaluate an object and pass it to ScriptEngine is enough:

```
QScriptEngine myEngine;
QScriptValue json = myEngine.evaluate("{\"k\":12, \"j\":14};");
qDebug()<<json.isObject();
```

Then we got "true", that is, we init a new object in the engine.

And if you would like to pass a normal C++ object into JS, I think `QScriptEngine::newObject()` and `QScriptEngine::newQObject()` is worth trying, though I didn't test them.

Comment: Thanks, i had already tried above.I need to form the key value pairs depending on data coming from native form a JSON object and Pass that object to Java Script in HTML page.

Comment: If I understand it right, you are trying to parse a Object from the engine and do some changes and send back to the engine. Then you should consider `QScriptValue::toVariant()`. However, I don't see any easy way to send the object back.